# Is it legal to use multiple + (plus) operators in one class?

Tags: html, css

Im currently coding a responsive design and I am at the point where the navigation is to collapse for mobile.

To achieve this I have created two `div`s and an `ul`. The `ul` contains my `nav` elements while the `div`s are going to display nav images for a drop down with mobile and tablet.

#### HTML

```
<div id="nav-tablet"><img></div>
<div id="nav-mobile"><img></div>
<ul></ul>
```

#### CSS

```css
#nav-tablet:hover + div + ul {
    display:inline;;
}
```

I've tested in and it works. I wanted to validate that it is valid CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's completely valid. You can use as many `+`s as you like. (Or  , or `>`, or `~` for that matter.)

If you do just want to match any `ul` *after* `#nav-tablet:hover`, though, `~` does that nicely.

```css
#nav-tablet:hover ~ ul
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. It's just as valid as `table>tbody>tr>td` - there's no limit to the number of combinators.

Just be aware that `+` can be a bit slower to process than other combinators, so don't overuse it.